# Do bats eat their babies?

Tags: behavior

There is a concept in Chinese that baby bats are easy to be unrecognizable to their parents. The idea is that after baby bats molt, even their parents won't be able to tell who they are. Not only that though, it is said that because their parents cannot tell who they are they will just ruthlessly eat them.

I've never heard of bats eating their young, and there is very little info about it online.

Which makes it seem like its a misconception more than anything.

Any truth to the idea that bats eat their babies?

Comment: what do you mean by molt,bats are mamals and as far as i know they do not molt.and eating their own children is not common in bats or in other mamals but it do happen from time to time.this question will probably be closed as off topic,it is not about pets.

Comment: Do we have a better site for this Question?

Comment: The site does, also, advertise itself as being for caretakers, breeders, veterinarians and trainers.

Comment: @trondhansen Bats do moult. See [Moulting matters: the importance of understanding moulting cycles in bats when using fur for endogenous marker analysis - Canadian Journal of Zoology](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/abs/10.1139/cjz-2013-0072)

Comment: @user3306356 - Yep but if you look [at the help page](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it specifies _this site is about pets and by that we mean an animal companion that is cared for in a domestic setting and not livestock, wildlife, and pests in and around your home_. As this is a question about wildlife rather than a pet, it is off-topic here. You could try and read the biology site's guidelines and ask there. (In the form it currently is, it would be closed on Biology). [Drop into chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) if you want more help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Any truth to the idea that bats eat their babies?

According to [Meat-eating and fish-eating bats](http://planet.uwc.ac.za/nisl/biodiversity/loe/page_222.htm):

> The Yellow-eared bat (Phyllostomus hastatus) even **feeds on other bats**.

But not members of their own species ([ADW: Phyllostomus hastatus: INFORMATION](https://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Phyllostomus_hastatus/#food_habits)):

> Greater spear-nosed bats have been documented eating mice (Mus musculus), birds (Cyanerpes cyaneus), and even **other bats, such as Hemiderma perspicillatum**. (Brosset, et al., 1996; Dunn, 1933; Raíces, et al., 2008; Willig, et al., 1993)

Having said that ([ADW: Phyllostomus hastatus: INFORMATION](http://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Phyllostomus_hastatus/)) goes on to say:

> When pups fall from their roost, they are retrieved by their mother. Females from the same social group as the pup and its mother will visit the fallen pup, their presence **providing protection from females of a different social group that may attack fallen pups**.

So it is possible that bats eat baby bats (but not their own offspring).